# Read file contents in git filter-branch

Tags: git

I have a git repository with a single file. I want to iterate over all the commits to the repository and for each commit extract the commit timestamp and the contents of the file. The extracted data should look like this:

```
12456789 <file contents>
13456789 <file contents 2>
14456789 <file contents 3>
```

I think that `git filter-branch` would be the right tool, but somehow it is not letting me operate on the repository files during the filtering.

The following command iterates over all the commits, but outputs nothing. If I replace it with `echo $GIT_COMMIT`, then the commit SHAs are printed correctly.

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter  'ls -l'
```

What I want to do is:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter  'echo -n "${GIT_AUTHOR_DATE} " >> extracted; cat some-file.txt >> extracted'
```

But the command cannot read the `some-file.txt`.

---

Is there a way to get access to the actual files of each commit? The documentation for `--tree-filter` states:

> The argument is evaluated in shell with the working directory set to the root of the checked out tree.

Which sounds like exactly what I want, except that the checked out tree is always empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not rewriting the tree so you don't need `git filter-branch` at all. Just run through all commits with `git rev-list` and process every commit. For example:

```
git rev-list master |
while read commit_id; do
    author_date=`git --no-pager show --format=%ad -q $commit_id`
    echo -n "$author_date "
    git --no-pager show $commit_id:some-file.txt
    echo  # Add an empty line; esp. useful for the commits where `some-file.txt` doesn't exist
done
```

One liner:

```
git rev-list master | while read commit_id; do author_date=`git --no-pager show --format=%ad -q $commit_id`; echo -n "$author_date "; git --no-pager show $commit_id:TODO; echo; done
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I was overcomplicating things.